# Seeing if a record already exists when creating an account

Tags: vb.net, dbnull

Hi I am trying to create an account system for my access database and I am suffering from the error "Operator '>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'." I have searched for fixes to my problem but can't find any answers which are working or helping? I'm pretty new to coding so any useful advice is appreciated

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
Dim myqry As String = Nothing
Dim mycmd As New OleDbCommand 



mycmd.Connection = conn
    mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT studentUser from tblStudents;"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = mycmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim value As Boolean = False
    While dr.Read

        If dr(0) > 0 Then
            value = True
        End If
    End While

    If value = True Then
        MsgBox("Username Already Exists, Please enter a new one")


    Else

        Dim sqlQry As String

        sqlQry = "INSERT INTO tblStudents(studentName, TutorGroup, studUser, studPass) VALUES(student_Name, student_Group, student_Username , student_Password)"

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Your account has successfully been created")
        Me.Hide()
        Login_Student.Show()
    End If
```

Comment: is the name column `studentUser`, `studentName` or `studUser` - your code cant seem to decide.  If there is a `studentUser` column then the SELECT query will bring back all rows in the DB - its not actually checking if a specific name exists.  You could also use COUNT to see if the desired name exists to avoid DBNull

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a constraint on the account, for example, unique by studentname.

Then wrap your insert call with Try...Catch:

```
sqlQry = "INSERT INTO tblStudents(studentName, TutorGroup, studUser, studPass) VALUES(student_Name, student_Group, student_Username , student_Password)"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, conn)
Try
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As ConstraintException
  MsgBox("Username Already Exists, Please enter a new one")
End Try
```

Doing a read first, then write will not work with concurrency, because another user may write an account in between your check and the actual write.

Comment: You forgot to add cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq: You are right, sorry about that. I fixed it now.

Comment: Is it good practice to rely on an exception to handle code flow? You are coding an assumption that there is a constraint at the db level.

Comment: @Spevy: It is a good practice to handle concurrency. Doing a Try...Catch is the only way to handle concurrency in this case. If there isn't a constraint or primary key on DB, there is no way to handle concurrency, so one must be added in order for the system to work. Regardless of concurrency, you do want to have at least Try...Finally to clean up resources, or better Try...Catch ex As SqlException...Finally to also do a rollback, if necessary. You can also use `Using` for connection.